# How to use CSS Selector for selecting element after specific element?

Tags: javascript, css

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li class="element1">Element 1</li>
  <li class="element1">Element 1</li>
  <li class="element2">Element 2</li>
  <li class="element1">Element 1</li>
  <li class="element2">Element 2</li>
  <li class="element1">Element 1 (Target)</li>
  <li class="element1">Element 1</li>
</ul>
```

Need css selector to select 6th item as it should after element2, its dynamic and I want element1 which ever is last and after element2

Comment: It would be easier to use JS to target the specific element. If you can use jQuery, you may use the function `.next()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to use JavaScript (not CSS only approach), you can achieve your goal using the following codes (assume you can use jQuery framework):

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="element1">Element 1</li>
  <li class="element1">Element 1</li>
  <li class="element2">Element 2</li>
  <li class="element1">Element 1</li>
  <li class="element2">Element 2</li>
  <li class="element1">Element 1 (Target)</li>
  <li class="element1">Element 1</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('.element2').last().next().css('color', '#F00');
});
```

The function `.last()` finds the last occurrence of the element with the class name `element2`, while the function `.next()` selects the immediate element after. In your case, you cannot use the CSS pseudo class `:last-of-type` unless you are selecting HTML tags (e.g. `<a>`, `<p>`, etc.) instead of CSS class.

JSFiddle demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/xyavgw3j/10/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child(n)` selector. You can specify value of `n` as a repeating pattern. Ex. `2n + 1` will select all child elements at odd index.

```css
ol li:nth-child(6) {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li>I</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: It needs to be dynamic

Comment: Please explain in your question what else is expected

Comment: List is pretty dynamic nth selector will select specific element at some possition, I need first element after element2, let me know if this make sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [+ in css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator). 
for the below html

```
    <li>element1</li>
    <li>element1</li>
    <li>element2</li>
    <li>element1></li>
    <li id="someElement">element2></li>
    <li><element1></li>
```

selector would be. `#someELement + li`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague and I'm guessing its a language barrier at this point. Maybe you can screenshot and edit an image to get your question a bit more sense? Or just provide the code as is.

If you want to select the second element of a dynamic list you can use the selector below. I also added a stop so it won't ever select the first child when the list is too small.

Hopefully this helps you in the right direction.

```css
ul li:not(:first-child):nth-last-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>A</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

There are more ways you can use selectors.
Check out https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
for CSS Selector Reference.

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li> <!--red-->
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
  <li>item5</li> <!--blue-->
  <li>item6</li> <!--green-->
</ul>
```

Option 1 - Selects every li element that is the last child of its parent

```
<style>
   ul li:last-child {
     color: green;
   }
</style>
```

Option 2 - Selects every li element that is the second child of its parent

```
<style>
   ul li:nth-child(2) {
     color: red;
   }
</style>
```

Option 3 - Selects every li element that is the second child of its parent, counting from the last child

```
<style>
   ul li:nth-last-child(2) {
     color: blue;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: There are two elements, element1 and element2 and list is dynamic, need to select first element1 which is after last element2, let me know if this make sense to you.

Comment: Please quote references from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) instead of w3schools. Also, the example HTML is incorrect. Use valid HTML comment block like this: `<!-- red -->`

Comment: @Raptor Whats wrong with w3schools? Are the contents of provided link not correct?

Comment: w3schools once contains a lot of incorrect/misleading information (which developers should avoid it), while MDN is a much better & more reputable choice.